# Статическая переменная пользовательского типа

Tags: c++

Как правильно объявить статическую переменную в данном контексте?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct link
{
    int data;
    link *next;
};

class some
{
private:
        static link *first;
public:
        some(int d)
        {
            link *newlink = new link;
            newlink->data = d;
            newlink->next = first;
            first = newlink;
        }
        void Show()
        {
            link *current = first;
            while(current)
            {
                cout << current->data << endl;
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
};

link some::first = nullptr;

int main()
{
    some ob1(1), ob2(2), ob3(3);
    ob3.Show();

    return 0;
}
```

Ошибки:

> conflicting declaration ‘link some::first’  link some::first =
>   nullptr;
>
> previous declaration as ‘link* some::first’  static link *first;
>
> some::first’ outside of class is not definition [-fpermissive] link
>   some::first = nullptr;

Comment: Статистическую, говорите ...

Answer (score 1):

В классе эта переменная объявлена как указатель

```
static link *first;
```

Однако определена не как указатель

```
link some::first = nullptr;
```

Напишите

```
link * some::first = nullptr;
```